# How to pull data from remote server database in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dbi, remote-server

I am using tiny_tds for connecting to remote database, which is only used for MySQL and Sql server. Is their is any other gem available which can access any vendor database?

Comment: What database are you trying to connect to? There's quite a few strategies for accomplishing this, so if you explained a little more specifically why you are trying to connect to a *separate* database, we can come up with a better answer for you.

Comment: Currently am using sql server. But am looking for solution which can access any vendor database.

Comment: Am migrating data from one database to other database.

Comment: There are dozens of different database servers out there, no gem is going to be able connect to them all. You may need to look in a different direction. Possibly exporting to a file in the external database and importing it in yours? More information with specific examples would help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16031080/dbiinterfaceerror-could-not-load-driver-uninitialized-constant-mysqlerror:- can you please have look at this question, currently am trying to use ruby DBI, but am facing some problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not understanding how database access works.

We use a driver to talk to a database. The database vendors have different protocols that are used to connect, so a driver handles that.

Above that layer we'd have an API that talks to the driver. That'd be something like DBI, which knows how to talk to different drivers. We still have to write using the query language of the database but DBI gives us some advantages. It's a pain to convert from one database to another, because usually all the queries change and the inconsistencies between "standards" show up.

Above that layer we'd have something like ActiveRecord or Sequel, which are ORMs, and are mostly DBM agnostic. They allow us to use a consistent language to define our connections to databases, create queries and handle interactions. If we want to talk to a different database manager, we install the driver, change the connection string, and the rest should work.

This is a huge time savings and a "very good thing". You can use SQLite for your proof-of-concepts, and something like PostgreSQL, MySQL, or Oracle for your production system, without changing queries. Only the DSN/connection string changes usually.

Read through Sequel's "[Connecting to a database](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/files/doc/opening_databases_rdoc.html)" document to get an idea what ORMs can do, along with "[Sequel: The Database Toolkit for Ruby](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/files/README_rdoc.html)" and "[Cheat Sheet](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/files/doc/cheat_sheet_rdoc.html)" for an idea what Sequel can do.